# how to read data stored in output of findcontour function in opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv, components, labeling

I want to label objects in a binary image using find contour and drawcontour function.

I also want to know what data is stored in the output array of findcontour function.

Further, are there any other suitable methods to do the above?

Comment: findContours() gives you a `vector<vector<Point>>` that is - for each contour found, a list of hull points.  if you wanted labels, look at [connectedComponents](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a)

Answer (score 0):

@berak's comment answered it already. I'll just add to the part of how does the output look like. Consider a 35x62 image whose 5 times enlarged version is below. The image has 6 blobs or objects each of which has a corresponding contour.

[image]

The above image was stored in Mat object `im`. `findContour` was applied as

`cv::findContours(im.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);`

The output of findContour is a `vector<vector<Point>>` object `contours` which looks like:

[image]

So, it has 6 elements each corresponding to one contour. Let's take `contours[0]` for example. It looks like:

[image]

`contours[0]` has five elements, each of which stores the coordinates of the pixels which form the contour.